# Is there a way to split a date range spanning over months to consecutive date ranges?

Tags: python, datetime, time-series

I have a series of start date and end date against a certain value.

The start date and the end date can start in any date in any month and end in any month.

I want to process the data so that I can get the value for each monthly range.

The data looks like this

```
           start          end               units    

        2017-10-10  2017-11-12               36.5
        2017-11-12  2017-12-12               15.2
        2017-12-12  2018-02-18               27.9
```

The expected output is

```
           start          end               units    

        2017-10-10  2017-10-31               36.5
        2017-11-1   2017-11-12               36.5
        2017-11-12  2017-11-30               15.2
        2017-12-1   2017-12-12               15.2
        2017-12-12  2017-12-31               27.9
        2018-01-01  2018-01-31               27.9
        2018-02-01  2018-02-28               27.9
```

P.S  - Mind how the last range is changing - a span from December to February - binned into 3 months.